# IE calls functions twice on ajaxified website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, history.js

I have strange problem for which I can't think of a solution. I have written some Javascript code to load some content through a AJAX call which also does some animation. To make the website functional I use jQuery with [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/). This is the script:

```
(function (window, undefined) {
    getContent(true); // Function that gets the initial content via AJAX and does some animation
                      // The parameter specifies that the call to the function is onload

    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(event){ 
       getContent(); 
    });

    function getContent(onload){
       if(onload == true){
         // Do onload stuff. Only slightly differs from other event calls
         // If there is no state given define default one ie 'home'
         alert('onload event triggered'); // For debug purposes
       } else {
         // Do other event stuff
         alert('click event triggered'); // For debug purposes
       }
     }

    somelinks.on('click',a,function(){ // Setup some eventlisteners that push the state });

})(window);
```

In browsers that support the HTML5 History/State API (Firefox, Chrome) this works flawless. On a load or reload of a specific url or on a click event the function does its work.

In IE it also works (with hashes ofcourse), however when I reload a page (ie example.com/#/test) the first as well as the second 'getContent()' function. So in Firefox a reload triggers the onload event alert, but in IE the onload event and the click event alert are triggered.

What I need is a way of structering my code or a logical check to prevent IE from calling the second getContent(). I've searched for similar problems (keywords: IE, History.js, etc.) but nothing to be found.

Hope somebody can help me with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(function (window, undefined) {

    var getContentOK = true;

    getContent(true);

    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(event){
       getContent(false);
    });

    function getContent(onload){
       if (getContentOK === true) {

           if(onload == true){
               // Do onload stuff. Only slightly differs from other event calls
               // If there is no state given define default one ie 'home'
               alert('onload event triggered'); // For debug purposes
           } else {
               // Do other event stuff
               alert('click event triggered'); // For debug purposes
           }

           getContentOK = false;
           setTimeout(function () {
               getContentOK = true;
           }, 500);
       }
     }

    somelinks.on('click',a,function(){ // Setup some eventlisteners that push the state });

})(window);
```

This will throttle the `statechange` event handler to only run `getContent()` once every 500ms.

Notice that I added some boolean flags, one to throttle the `statechange` event handler and one to mimic your `onload` variable. `firstRun` will output `true` on the first run and then `false` on each subsequent runs.

This is not as good a solution as figuring out what is happening with the `History.js` plugin but I have no experience with it so I can't say why IE is firing two events.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, the problems occurs on a on load/reload so setting a variable to check it won't help me I'm afraid. Thanks for this tip though, might come in handy

Comment: On page-load if two events are firing one right after the other, then throttling will only let the first one run...

Comment: Sorry Jasper, didn't understand your solution. Is throttling a common solution for solving these kinds of problems?

Comment: My experience is mostly with virtual mouse events on mobile devices. They will sometimes trigger two `click` events and I throttle them to only accept the first. I have also done this with the `resize` event since it fires so many times in most browsers. In both cases the throttling gives the desired outcome. In the case of using a `setTimeout` once when the `statechange` event fires you won't get a whole lot of overhead CPU usage. It's when you throttle using `setInterval` that can get expensive. I believe I started doing this after reading a blog post from John Resig.

Comment: I tried your solution Jasper, but the trigger is not aviable for the History.Adapter object. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: I very well may have tried to run a jQuery function on a non-jQuery object. I think the best solution would be to add the throttle code to the `getContent()` function and run it like you were before. I'll update my code...

Comment: Now that the throttle code is in the `getContent()` function, you can call `getContent()` from wherever you want and it will only run once every 500ms.

Comment: Great Jasper, your solution worked! However working with the History API (even with History,js) is kinda tricky for me.